# Can we artificially produce a species that would be able to live on Antarctic ice sheet?

Tags: genetics, extremophiles, artificial-selection

Can we artificially produce a multicellular species that would be able to live on Antarctic ice sheet?

By means of genetic engineering, selection etc.

**UPDATE**

There are organisms, called Watermelon snow or, scientifically Chlamydomonas nivalis, which do exactly that: populate snow. They are not multi-cellular, but eukaryotic (not bacterial), photosynthetic and form extensive colonies. They already populate both Arctica and Antarctica. They prefer snow to ice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some bacteria manage to live there, besides the arctic cold that kills most of the other animals.... So, you mean to create an organisation, from that kind of bacteria, or just a colony of some monocytes?

Comment: There's plenty of wildlife in Antartica already ([wiki > wildlife of Antartica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildlife_of_Antarctica))

Comment: I know this is closed, but I just want to mention one of my favourite papers: https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v310/n5974/abs/310225a0.html :)